# What is $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(0, {1\over n}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(0, {1\over n}\right)?$$I suspect it is the empty set, and we would see this by using the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ or something like that, but I have no idea on how to prove it. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose the set isn't empty. Then there exists a postive $x$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(x<\dfrac 1 n\right)$. But due to the Archimedean Property what do you know?

Answer (score 4):

You got it right: it is indeed an empty set. To prove this, suppose it isn't empty, that is $\exists x\in\mathbb{R},\,x\in\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left( 0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Since there's an intersection, this means that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,x\in\left( 0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$, that is $x>0$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},n<\frac{1}{x}$. Guess you found the contradiction :D